# Why does play.libs.Json.toJson return an empty object?

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.3

Why can't I convert my Person object into Json?

My Person Model:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String value;   
}
```

A controller method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import models.Person;
import play.Logger;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.index;

import java.util.List;

import static play.data.Form.form;
import static play.libs.Json.toJson;

...

public static Result getJsonPersons() {
    List<Person> persons = new Model.Finder(Long.class, Person.class).all();
    JsonNode jsonNode = toJson(persons);
    Logger.debug("JSON > "+jsonNode.toString());
    return ok(jsonNode);
}
```

Action route:

```
GET   /persons      controllers.Application.getJsonPersons()
```

Resulting JSON returned by the controller method:

```
[{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Comment: Show the import from `toJson` and `JsonNode`. Also add your play version.

Comment: I added in a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is related with field access modifiers in the Person class. Both fields are private hence `play.libs.Json.toJson` cannot access them. You have to provide appropriate getter methods or make these field public.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```